# How can I register a image_style theme function in my module which only works in my theme's template?

Tags: 7, theming

Is there a way to tell drupal that my module has a theme function which usually only works in my theme?

If I write in my theme's template.php:

```
function mytheme_image_style($variables) {

  // Determine the dimensions of the styled image.
  $dimensions = array(
    'width' => $variables['width'],
    'height' => $variables['height'],
  );

  image_style_transform_dimensions($variables['style_name'], $dimensions);

  $variables['width'] = $dimensions['width'];
  $variables['height'] = $dimensions['height'];

  // Determine the URL for the styled image.

  $variables['path'] = image_style_url($variables['style_name'], $variables['path']);

  // do additional stuff


  return theme('image', $variables);
}
```

everything works fine. If I move this code to a module it does not work, though:

```
function mymodule_image_style($variables) {

  // code


  return theme('image', $variables);
}
```

How can I use the theme_image_style function/hook in my module?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`hook_theme_registry_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7) to replace the callback function for the `image_style` theme. Something like this should do it:

```
function MYMODULE_theme_registry_alter(&$registry) {
  $registry['image_style']['function'] = 'mymodule_image_style';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use [hook_image_styles_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.api.php/function/hook_image_styles_alter/7) instead of your function.

Here is an example found on [drupal.org](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.api.php/function/hook_image_default_styles/7):

```
<?php
function mymodule_image_styles_alter(&$styles) {
  $styles['myimagestyle'] = array(
    'label' => 'My Image Style',
    'effects' => array(
      array(
        'name' => 'image_scale',
        'data' => array(
          'width' => 500,
          'height' => 300,
          'upscale' => 1,
        ),
        'weight' => 0,
      ),
    ),
    'name' => 'myimagestyle', // You need this and the next line to avoid PHP notices
    'storage' => IMAGE_STORAGE_NORMAL,
  );

  return $styles;
}
?>
```

Comment: this will just register/ add my image style as a possible image style to pick from, not quite what i am looking for but thanks :)

Comment: Sorry I thought you were asking for "How can I use the theme_image_style function/hook in my module?". My answer was "with hook_image_styles_alter". What are you looking for in addition?

Comment: how to call the theme_image_style function in a module rather than in my theme's template

Comment: oh, you want to keep your theme function in template.php but invoke it in a module?

Comment: To call mytheme_image_style() in template.php, you have to right down "return theme('image_style', $variables);" in your module.

Comment: please read more carefully: instead of having this function in my template/theme, i want to have it in my module, but the hook/theme function does not get invoked

Comment: Is it your problem? https://api.drupal.org/comment/12964#comment-12964

Comment: You're looking for `hook_theme_registry_alter'` @Alex

Comment: Hopefully @Clive understood what you meant :p Sorry for my poor comprehension.

Comment: @Clive could you give me a hint how to code this? I basically need to run the function just defined in my module, how would that look using the registry hook?